# Let $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in J}$ be a net in a topological space $X$. Show that if $J$ is a ﬁnite set then the net converges? ...

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, nets

Let $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in J}$ be a net in a topological space $X$. Show that if $J$ is a ﬁnite set then the net converges? ...

Why does it have to converge?

I don't understand why with nets this is true, whilst with sequences it isn't. 
if the value alternates between two values shouldn't it never converge?

Comment: You are confused between the set J being finite and the values the sequence can take being a finite set. The sequence $\{1,1,1...\}$ is an infinite sequence even though every element in the sequence is just 1.

Comment: so for example: 
X=Z+
J= x part of Z between (1-10) 

and the sequence be : if j is even, 1 if j is odd 0

is this not a net?

Comment: If $J$ is finite then, because it's directed, it has a greatest element $j_m$, and then the net converges to $x_{j_m}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of the concept of "net", $J$ must be a [directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set). Being finite, it must have a unique maximal element $j_\infty$, i.e. $j \le j_\infty \ \forall j \in J$ (intuitively, you can "reach" infinity, which you cannot do in $\Bbb N$). Then $x_{j_\infty}$ is the limit of the net.

EDIT:

To clarify the question in the comment: let $J = \{1, 2, \dots, 10\}$ with the usual order. Let $x_1 = x_3 = \dots = x_9 = 0$ and $x_2 = x_4 = \dots = x_{10} = 1$. Let us show that $0$ cannot be the limit of this net.

Take a neighbourhood $V$ of $0$, small enough such that $1 \notin V$. The definition of ["limit of a net"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29#Limits_of_nets) says that there should exist $n_V \in J$ such that for every $n \ge n_V$ we should have $x_n \in V$. Notice that no matter who $n_V$ would be, clearly $10 \ge n_V$. But do we have $1 = x_{10} \in V$? Of course not, by how we chose $V$. This shows that $0$ does not satisfy the definition of "limit of a net".

On the other hand, $1$ does satisfy the definition: choose any neighbourhood $V$ of $1$ and always choose $n_V = 10$. Then all the terms with index greater than $10$ (which in fact means just $x_{10}$) are in $V$, and you just don't care about the first $9$ terms.

Comment: if we take 
X=Z+
J=(1 to 10) 
then it satisfies directness, 
but then for a sequence: if j is even, 1 if j is odd 0 
it doesn't converge. 
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @leodtorchia: Take a look at my edit.